# Objective-c hit test on calayer

Tags: objective-c, calayer

I have a view hierarchy set up like so:

```
UIViewController* gameBoard
    FEG_Navigator* vNavigation
       FEG_Controller* vController1
       FEG_Controller* vController2
```

in FEG_Controller I over ride draw rect with this code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    arc = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    arc.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(100, 50) radius:self.radius startAngle:M_PI endAngle:M_PI/150 clockwise:self.isClockwise].CGPath;
    arc.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)-self.radius,
                               CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)-self.radius);
    arc.fillColor = self.clrCircle.CGColor;
    arc.cornerRadius = 0.5;

    [self.layer addSublayer:arc];

}
```

and in the init I have self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

When I init the controllers in gameBoard I add tap gestures to them -

```
//set up controllers
    UITapGestureRecognizer* controller1Tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moveTurret:)];
    controller1 = [[FEG_RA_Controller alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-22, 3.0, 35.0, 35.0)];
    [controller1 makeController:self.clrUserColor :35.0 :1.0:YES];
    controller1.tag = 100;
    [controller1 addGestureRecognizer:controller1Tap];
    [vNavigator addSubview:controller1];
```

and right now, all moveTurret does is log the tag of the sender's view (UITapGestureRecognizer).

I get nothing. So I dug around on the interwebs and found a nifty site with some interesting stuff, including this:

http://sketchytech.blogspot.com/2012/10/the-secret-life-of-calayer-part-2.html

So CALayers are outside the responder chain, that makes sense. Conceptually I get what the author is explaining, I'm just having trouble applying it to my situation - where should touchesEnded go? In the FEG_Controller?

Answer (score 0):

touchesEnded would be implemented in your FEG_Controller, which I'm assuming is a UIView subclass. This may just be a typo but are you using the right subclass? You have a FEG_Controller declared and are implementing a FEG_RA_Controller. Just making sure. Using touchesEnded would replace the tap gesture recognizer all together, basically you'd be writing your own gesture recognizer which isn't needed (or beneficial, you'd be losing some of the tap gesture recognizer conveniences). If you want to keep your gesture recognizer in your view controller then just do a check in your moveTurret:

```
if ([arc containsPoint:[tap locationInView:self]])
    //then move the turret
else
    //don't
```

And move your gesture recognizer from the FEG_Controller's frame to the main view controller's bounds:

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:controller1Tap]
```